# Error trapping in EF Core with an Azure Function in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I have a function:

```
 public async Task<List<DTO.Currency_DTO>> GetCurrencyAsync()
        {
            try
            {
                return await _ripple_primary_context.RipplCurrencies.Select(p => new DTO.Currency_DTO
                {
                    currency_id = p.CurrencyId,
                    currency_name = p.CurrencyName,
                    currency_alpha_code = p.CurrencyAlphaCode

                }).ToListAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
```

This returns an custom DTO (only certain fields). What is the best way to try and catch a READ error? i.e what's within the catch block and is there a certain exception for READ errors - I can only find WRITE errors.

Also what would be best to return when an error occurs? I guess it still needs be in the Shape Of the DTO model.

Comment: If that function encounters an error that it can not fix, why should it return your DTO in any shape? Log the exception and rethrow it so the rest of your application also gets the info that some error occured. Handling the actual exception (e.g. turn exception X in http response code Y) can then be done with a custom middleware for example

Comment: I agree it should not return the DTO in any shape, i get that so how can i change my function to return an error ? at the moment it is only returning the DTO as a list ? Sorry for my ignorance here its just that i am pretty new to this ef core stuff.

Comment: Simply remove your try/catch or do 'throw ex' in your catch-block...let the exception bubble up the call stack, then handle it where/when appropriate. This has nothing to do with EF Core specifically. I can not tell you more about the where/when since I'm not familiar with exception handling in Azure-Functions

Comment: In its current state I'd prefer to remove the try/catch as it does nothing (even if you'd add the 'throw ex'). Use try/catch if your app can do somthing about a particular exception or if you would like return a specific Exception yourself.